# Can't identify javascript (undefined)

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm making a small game for school using a tutorial, my variables are not getting identified and i can't find out what it is. In the getEnemy.innerHTML it can't find any of the variables. The player works but the enemy doesn't. Thanks alot and go easy on me!

```
setPreFight: function() {
    let getHeader = document.querySelector(".header");
    let getActions = document.querySelector(".actions");
    let getArena = document.querySelector(".arena");
    getHeader.innerHTML = '<p>Task: Find an enemy!</p>';
    getActions.innerHTML= '<a href= "#" class="btn-prefight" onclick="GameManager.setFight()">Search for Enemy! </a>';
    getArena.style.visibility = "visible";
},
setFight: function() {
    let getHeader = document.querySelector(".header");
    let getActions = document.querySelector(".actions");
    let getEnemy = document.querySelector(".enemy");
    //create enemy
    let enemy00 = new Enemy("Goblin, 100, 0, 50, 100, 100");
    let enemy01 = new Enemy("Troll, 200, 0, 150, 80, 150");
    let chooseRandomEnemy = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2));
    switch (chooseRandomEnemy) {
        case 0:
          enemy = enemy00;
           break;
        case 1:
          enemy = enemy01;
           break;
    }
    getHeader.innerHTML = '<p>Task: Choose your move </p>';
    getActions.innerHTML = '<a href= "#" class="btn-prefight" onclick="PlayerMoves.calcAttack()">Attack! </a>';
    getEnemy.innerHTML = '<img src="img/avatar-enemies/ ' + enemy.enemyType + '.png" alt="' + enemy.enemyType + '"class="img-avatar"><div><h3>' + enemy.enemyType + '</h3> <p class=="health-enemy">Health: ' + enemy.health + '</p><p>Mana ' + enemy.mana + '</p><p>Strength: ' + enemy.strength + '</p> <p>Agility: ' + enemy.agility + '</p><p> Speed: ' + enemy.speed + '</p></div>';
}
```

}

I hope that somebody can help me find why it's showing undefined. I think it's right in front of me but just can't find it at all!

Comment: I'd suggested some additional debugging. After `let chooseRandomEnemy = ...` add `console.log(chooseRandomEnemy);` to see which random choice was made.  After the `switch (chooseRandomEnemy) { ... }` add `console.dir(enemy);` to see which enemy was chosen

Comment: I'd guess that `enemy` is actually not set at all in your `switch` statement

Comment: Show where you are defining "enemy." We see the attempted value assignment but not the instantiation of the variable.

Comment: Travis is right. Where do you actually say 'let enemy;' to define the var?

Comment: I'm also curious what the Enemy class takes as args. Seems new Enemy("Troll, 200, 0, 150, 80, 150"); should actually be new Enemy("Troll", "200", "0", "150", "80", "150");

Comment: Hey, this + what Emil said work for me thanks alot! Was slamming my head for to long!

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the enemy variable, like this:

```
//create enemy
let enemy;
let enemy00 = new Enemy("Goblin, 100, 0, 50, 100, 100");
let enemy01 = new Enemy("Troll, 200, 0, 150, 80, 150");
```

Comment: I'm betting the Enemy class takes six arguments, and not one string as well. Haven't seen the function signature, but It would otherwise be weird to include all that in one arg.

Comment: I agree, it probably takes six arguments. Didn't spot that right away.

Comment: Thanks alot Emil!